# AutoBean Compile Error: "Parameterization is not simple..."

Tags: json, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm trying to use AutoBean on the server and client to send and receive json data through AppEngines channel API. I don't want to store this data in the datastore. I already have a Proxy for this object that I use for the RequestFactoryServlet (which underneath just uses AutoBean anyways), so this should be doable. Instead of writing up a new Proxy for the object that exactly duplicates the Proxy for the RequestFactoryServlet, I'd like to just use the proxy that I use for the RequestFactoryServlet. The only problem is that I get an error while compiling that comes from my AutoBeanFactory.

> Invoking generator
>   com.google.web.bindery.autobean.gwt.rebind.AutoBeanFactoryGenerator
>              [ERROR] The com.wmba.wmbaapp.shared.ObjectProxy parameterization is not simple, but the obj method does not provide a
>   delegate

So I'm not really sure what to do here. It seems like before I added the client side in, it's able to serialize the object into JSON just fine, but for some reason it doesn't like this. It sounds like it wants a delegate from me, but I can't find anything on this from the internet.

Anyone have any ideas?

Note: I also tried the same thing with EntityProxy (which is the base of the RequestFactory framework from what I read on the AutoBean page, but I get the same error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `EntityProxy` defines the `stableId` method which is not a getter (name doesn't start with `get`). That makes it a *not simple* bean, for which AutoBeans require a real bean instance to be wrapped in the created `AutoBean` (the *delegate*, passed as an argument of the type of the `AutoBean` –`ObjectProxy` in your case– to your `obj` method of the `AutoBeanFactory`).

In other words, AutoBeans expects your `obj` method to be of the form:

```
AutoBean<ObjectProxy> obj(ObjectProxy toWrap);
```

The simplest solution is to not try to reuse the entity proxy with AutoBeans.

---

You might be able to make it work though by annotating your `AutoBeanFactory` with:

```
@Category(EntityProxyCategory.class)
```

You might have to add `@NoWrap(EntityProxyId.class)` too, see http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/vm/InProcessRequestFactory.java

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! I appreciate the explanation. It compiled now and appears to be working. I just had to add @AutoBeanFactory.Category(value=EntityProxyCategory.class) to my AutoBeanFactory interface. Thanks for the simple solution. Makes me feel a lot better when I don't have to manage all these different pieces of code :-)

Comment: Hey, do you know how I would be able to do this with a List or an Array of the proxy object? I've tried a few different ways with the same error as above each time.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I'm getting my objects read from a JSON so I can't control how they are created (which of the factory methods is called). Is there a way to say to AutoBeanCodex.decode to create a wrapped AutoBean ???

Comment: I posed a separate question @Thomas Broyer for that

Answer (score 3):

It turned out for me that I had a property setter that had an empty parameter list in my Ojbect interface.  It didn't have anything to do with the factory, except for the interface the factory was trying to create a proxy for:

```
interface Factory {
  AutoBeans<MyObject> createObject();
}
interface MyObject {
  String getProperty();
  void setProperty();
}
```

A bone-headed mistake but held me up with this precise compiler error.  Adding the Category annotation as mentioned in the previous answer identified the faulty property setter.